# Dagger 2 presenter injection returning null

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, butterknife

I am attempting to add Dagger 2 to my Android Project. 
My application have following screen

1. Login extends Base activity
2. Navigation Activity extends Base activity
3. MW Activity extents Navigation Activity

Presenter Injection is working fine in Login and navigation activity where as in  MW activity it return null

Butter Knife is also not working in MW Activity where as working fine in other activities

Following are my classes 
Application class

```
public class abcApplication extends Application {
    ApplicationComponent mApplicationComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .build();
        mApplicationComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public static abcApplication get(Context context) {
        return (abcApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
        return mApplicationComponent;
    }

    // Needed to replace the component with a test specific one
    public void setComponent(ApplicationComponent applicationComponent) {
        mApplicationComponent = applicationComponent;
    }


}
```

Base activity

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityComponent mActivityComponent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    public ActivityComponent activityComponent() {
        if (mActivityComponent == null) {
            mActivityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                    .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                    .applicationComponent(abcApplication.get(this).getComponent())
                    .build();
        }
        return mActivityComponent;
    }

}
```

Navigation Activity

```
public class NavigationActivity extends BaseActivity implements NavigationView {

    @Inject
    DataClient mDataClient;

    @Bind(R.id.drawer_layout)
    protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.navList)
    ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    private ExpandableListAdapter mExpandableListAdapter;
    private List<String> mExpandableListTitle;
    private Map<String, List<String>> mExpandableListData;

    private Map<String, String> activityMap;

    private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;

    @Inject
    NavigationPresenter navigationPresenter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        activityComponent().inject(this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        navigationPresenter.attachView(this);


        }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    navigationPresenter.detachView();
    }
        }
```

MW Activity

```
public class MWActivity extends NavigationActivity implements MWView{
    private MWPagerAdapter mMWPagerAdapter;


    @Inject
    MWPresenter MWPresenter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        DrawerLayout mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        MWPresenter.attachView(this);
        MWPresenter.getMarketData();
        }

    }
```

Logcat : 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.abc.xyz, PID: 21542

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.xyz/com.abc.trading.xyz.ui.main.mw.view.MWActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)

```
@PreActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = ActivityModule.class)

    public interface ActivityComponent {

        void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
        void inject(NavigationActivity navigationActivity);
        void inject(MWActivity mWActivity);
        void inject(MWTabFragment mWTabFragment);
        void inject(MWDetailsActivity mWDetailsActivity);


    }
```

Comment: Please provide your component where you habe your `inject(activity)` methods

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I Have updated my description please check

Comment: @DavidMedenjak even butter knife is not working in MWActivity activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Activity Component was not injected activityComponent().inject(this);
>   in MW Activity

```
public class MWActivity extends NavigationActivity implements MWView{
    private MWPagerAdapter mMWPagerAdapter;


    @Inject
    MWPresenter MWPresenter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        activityComponent().inject(this);
        DrawerLayout mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        MWPresenter.attachView(this);
        MWPresenter.getMarketData();
        }

    }
```

ActivityComponent (Base Activity)

```
 public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityComponent mActivityComponent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    public ActivityComponent activityComponent() {
        if (mActivityComponent == null) {
            mActivityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                    .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                    .applicationComponent(OmsApplication.get(this).getComponent())
                    .build();
        }
        return mActivityComponent;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 issues regarding super- / sub types at hand.

1. Butterknife does [not support injection to super types](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/198)
2. Dagger does [not support injection to sub types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312911/can-i-just-inject-super-class-when-use-dagger2-for-dependency-injection)

As already pointed out, to solve 2. you would need to call `inject` in your `MWActivity`, and to use Butterknife you need to use a ViewHolder pattern within your super class to bind / inject the fields, since it will only inject `MWActivity` and not `NavigationActivity`.

Comment: I have done the same as you mentioned in your comment to solve issue with butter knife . I forgot to mentioned in my answer . Thanks a lot for your valuable support