# Kotlin Dagger not inject

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I recently move from java to kotlin, and try to implement dagger 2 for dependency injection.

I've add this to my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

Here is my module

```
@Module
class AppModule(val context : Context) {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext() = context
}
```

Here is my component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class))
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(application: Application)
}
```

Here is my Application

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var context : Context

    lateinit var appComponent : AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(AppModule(this.applicationContext))
                .build()
        appComponent.inject(this)
    }
}
```

Here is my activity

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        val context = (applicationContext as MyApplication).context
    }
}
```

and i get this error

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property context has not been initialized
```

This code is working in Java, any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `context` property is declared in the `MyApplication` class, but you're injecting the `Application` base class here:

```
fun inject(application: Application)
```

... which has no injectable properties. You have to make an `inject` method in your component for the specific class instead:

```
fun inject(application: MyApplication)
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326023/4465208) an answer explaining how you can use Dagger with hierarchies in more detail.

Comment: Thank you so muchhh, I've spend many hours just to find this one

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with Dagger. The error clearly states that you have declared a property with a `lateinit` but have not initialized it in Kotlin.

Comment: Sry i missed it, i accidentally delete @Inject when posting it. Suppose to be there & the issue still the same

Comment: Now I'm confused. You built `AppModule ` with the  `applicationContext` and then inject again in App? Why don't you just simply use applicationContext across the activities ?

Comment: I'm planning to inject not only context later, such as retrofit and other dependencies