# (DAGGER-ANDROID) Can not use @Inject on an Espresso Test and can not use mockWebServer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to create Espresso tests and using a `mockWebServer` the thing is when I try to create my `mockWebServer` it calls the real api call and I want to intercept it and mock the response.

My dagger organisation is  :

My App

```
open class App : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {

    lateinit var application: Application

    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerAppComponent.factory()
            .create(this)
            .inject(this)
        this.application = this
    }
}
```

Then MyAppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        RetrofitModule::class,
        RoomModule::class,
        AppFeaturesModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: App): AppComponent
    }
}
```

Then I've created this TestApp

```
class TestApp : App() {

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector

    override fun onCreate() {
        DaggerTestAppComponent.factory()
            .create(this)
            .inject(this)
    }
}
```

And this is my TestAppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        TestRetrofitModule::class,
        AppFeaturesModule::class,
        RoomModule::class]
)
interface TestAppComponent : AppComponent {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: App): TestAppComponent
    }
}
```

Note: Here I've created a new module, called `TestRetrofitModule` where the BASE_URL is "http://localhost:8080", I don't know if I need something else.

Also I've created the `TestRunner`

```
class TestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(
        cl: ClassLoader?,
        className: String?,
        context: Context?
    ): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApp::class.java.name, context)
    }

}
```

And put it on the `testInstrumentationRunner`

### Problem 1

I can not use

```
@Inject
lateinit var okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
```

because it says that it's not initialised.

### Problem 2 (Solved thanks Skizo)

My mockWebServer is not dispatching the responses even-though is not pointing the real api call, is pointing the one that I've put to the TestRetrofitModule, the thing is that I have to link that mockWebServer and Retrofit.

Comment: please edit your question with the code of the constructor of a class that extends your AbstractBaseTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with `mockWebServer` recently, what you need to do is to put a breakpoint and see what's the error, in my case I put it on my `BaseRepository` where I was doing the call, and found that the exception was :

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to localhost not permitted by network security policy
```

What I did to solve the problem is add this on my `manifest.xml`

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

But you may have to use other approaches you can take a look on [android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted).

Answer (score 3):

The setup you posted looks correct. As for `App` not being provided, you probably need to bind it in your component, since right now you're binding `TestApp` only. So you need to replace

```kotlin
fun create(@BindsInstance application: TestApp): TestAppComponent
```

with

```kotlin
fun create(@BindsInstance application: App): TestAppComponent
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but the thing is the Dispatcher is not working, how do I link the mockWebServer to the fake call?

Answer (score 1):

When I try to do something similar, I don't create two types of application-components, just one. I provide them with different inputs, based on whether it's for the actual `App` or for the `TestApp`. No need for `TestAppComponent` at all. E.g.

```
open class App : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {

    lateinit var application: Application

    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerAppComponent.factory()
            .create(this, createRetrofitModule())
            .inject(this)
        this.application = this
    }

    protected fun createRetrofitModule() = RetrofitModule(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
}

class TestApp : App() {
    override fun createRetrofitModule() = RetrofitModule("http://localhost:8080")
}


@Module
class RetrofitModule(private val baseUrl: String) {
    ...
    provide your Retrofit and OkHttpClients here and use the 'baseUrl'.
    ...
}
```

(not sure if this 'compiles' or not; I usually use the `builder()` pattern on a dagger-component, not the `factory()` pattern, but you get the idea).

The pattern here is to provide your app-component or its modules with inputs for the 'edge-of-the-world', stuff that needs to be configured differently based on the context in which the app would run (contexts such as build-flavors, app running on consumer device vs running in instrumentation mode, etc). Examples are `BuildConfig` values (such as base-urls for networking), interface-implementations to real or fake hardware, interfaces to 3rd party libs, etc.

Comment: There are two problems there, one that I can use localhost to be the same as mockwebserver and is working, the problem I guess that the ports are differents and that's why is not working, could be?

Comment: StuartDTO: Your second problem may have been answered by Skizo-ozᴉʞS earlier.

Comment: True, it did. Thanks. Now the problem is that I can not use Inject to get anything from TestAppComponent...

Answer (score 1):

How about `a dagger module` for your `Test Class` with a `ContributeAndroidInjector` in there and do `Inject` on a `@Before` method.

Your `TestAppComponent`:

```
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, TestAppModule::class])
interface TestAppComponent {
    fun inject(app: TestApp)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: TestApp): Builder
        fun build(): TestAppComponent
    }
}
```

`TestAppModule` like:

```
@Module
interface TestAppModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [Provider::class])
    fun activity(): MainActivity

    @Module
    object Provider {
        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideString(): String = "This is test."

    }

    // Your other dependencies here
}
```

And `@Before` method of `Test Class` you must be do:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    val instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
    val app = instrumentation.targetContext.applicationContext as TestApp

    DaggerTestAppComponent.builder().application(app).build().inject(app)

   // Some things other
}
```

An important thing, you must be have (on `build.gradle` module `app`):

```
kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$version_dagger"
kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$version"
```

Now, when you launch an `Activity` like `MainActivity`, Dagger will inject `dependencies` from your `TestAppModule` instead of `AppModule` before.

Moreover, If you want to `@Inject` to `Test Class`, you can add:

```
fun inject(testClass: TestClass) // On Your TestAppComponent
```

And then, you can call:

```
DaggerTestAppComponent.builder().application(app).build().inject(this) // This is on your TestClass
```

to Inject some dependencies to your `TestClass`.

Hope this can help you!!

Comment: Looks what I need, could you post like an example of what I have to do so I can try=

Comment: I supposed that, but it means that I have to add as much inject as test I have?...

Comment: No, when you create TestModule you can `inheritance` from `your main module` and do `override` on necessary dependencies...

Comment: @StuartDTO Maybe you can check an example at: https://github.com/dinhlamvn/uitestDagger. I have added an TestClass and do some inject dependencies with Dagger on there.

Comment: Now you have this `fun inject(test: ExampleInstrumentedTest)` but then if I want to inject it in another test I do not need it because I have this `BaseTest`?

Comment: Maybe that's not correct, because Dagger just `inject` to specify `Class`, that's reason you will have many `inject` method on `Component` or have `ContributeAndroidInjector` method on `Module`.

Comment: @StuartDTO you can get more detail in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312911/can-i-just-inject-super-class-when-use-dagger2-for-dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming that you are trying to inject OkHttpClient:

```
@Inject
lateinit var okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
```

in your TestApp class, and it fails. In order to make it work, you will need to add an inject method in your `TestAppComponent`, to inject the overriden TestApp, so that it becomes:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        TestRetrofitModule::class,
        AppFeaturesModule::class,
        RoomModule::class]
)
interface TestAppComponent : AppComponent {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: App): TestAppComponent
    }

    fun inject(testApp: TestApp)
}
```

The reason why this is required, is because Dagger is type based, and uses the type of each class to be injected/provided to determine how to generate the code at compile-time. In your case, when you try to inject the TestApp, dagger will inject its superclass (the App class), because it only know that it has to inject the App class. If you have a look at the AndroidInjector interface (that you use in your AppComponent), you will see that it is declared like:

```
public interface AndroidInjector<T> {
    void inject(T instance)
....
}
```

This means that it will generate a method:

```
fun inject(app App)
```

in the AppComponent. And this is why @Inject works in your App class, but does not work in your TestApp class, unless you explicitly provided it in the TestAppComponent.

Comment: So I have to inject it on every test? I mean in `@Before` do I have to inject it? How do I do inject it? I'm trying to do it with dagger-android without the field-injection?

Comment: @StuartDTO it is not quite clear where you want to inject the OkHttpClient, or if you need to inject the OkHttpClient. Since you have created a TestRetrofitModule, you do not need to inject the OkHttpClient anywhere. All the necessary wiring should be handled in your TestRetrofitModule class. My answer assumes that you tried to inject variables in the TestApp class, which is not automatically set as to be injected (because it does not have an inject method call in the TestApplicationComponent). All classes which have variables injected, should have an inject method call in a Component.

Comment: But in case I need to inject something like Room or some preferences, how do I get them  if I can not use @inject? Also, I'm creating the mockWebServer in the test and I thought it could be possible to have it as a provides but is giving me NOMTException

Comment: You can inject anything you like in your test classes. But in to achieve this, you should include an `inject()` function in your TestAppComponent and explicitly inject your test class. Unless you add an inject function in your TestAppComponent, and explicitly inject your Test case in your @Before method, the dependencies will not be supplied to your Test class.