# Android Studio Retrofit Call Failure

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to use Retrofit in my app via Java. I'm using [this worldtime API](http://worldtimeapi.org/). You can call this URL in your browser to see the response : http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Istanbul (response comes too late, just refresh your browser)

I added this line to my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I added these to `gradle`

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

I only want to see few keys of response, so I created a class `TimeForIstanbul.java`

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class TimeForIstanbul {
    @SerializedName("day_of_week")
    @Expose
    public Integer dayOfWeek;
    @SerializedName("utc_datetime")
    @Expose
    public String utcDatetime;
    @SerializedName("week_number")
    @Expose
    public Integer weekNumber;

    public Integer getDayOfWeek() {
        return dayOfWeek;
    }

    public void setDayOfWeek(Integer dayOfWeek) {
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    }

    public String getUtcDatetime() {
        return utcDatetime;
    }

    public void setUtcDatetime(String utcDatetime) {
        this.utcDatetime = utcDatetime;
    }

    public Integer getWeekNumber() {
        return weekNumber;
    }

    public void setWeekNumber(Integer weekNumber) {
        this.weekNumber = weekNumber;
    }
}
```

I created my interface `ApiService.java`

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface ApiService {
    @GET("Europe/Istanbul")
    Call<TimeForIstanbul> getTime();
}
```

And simply I edited my `MainActivity.java`

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private ApiService apiService;
    private String BASE_URL = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/";
    private Call<TimeForIstanbul> timeForIstanbulCall;
    private TimeForIstanbul timeForIstanbul;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRetrofitSettings();
    }
    private void setRetrofitSettings(){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
        timeForIstanbulCall = apiService.getTime();
        timeForIstanbulCall.enqueue(new Callback<TimeForIstanbul>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TimeForIstanbul> call, Response<TimeForIstanbul> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    timeForIstanbul = response.body();
                    System.out.println(timeForIstanbul.getDayOfWeek());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TimeForIstanbul> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Error is ");
                System.out.println(t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And when I run this app, I see

```
I/System.out: Error is 
    java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to worldtimeapi.org not permitted by network security policy
```

on logcat so it goes to `onFailure`. What am I missing? What is wrong here? My resource for this example is this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0xsUgxNFco)

Comment: `What am I missing? What is wrong here?` your error handling is wrong. does printing out `"ERRORRRRRRRRRRRR"` help you to know why it failed ? no, otherwise you wouldn't be asking here :) you should be printing out the actual exception from the throwable so that you can see what's wrong

Comment: Print what t.getMessage() is saying please

Comment: @a_local_nobody you are exactly right, thanks for advice :) I edited question, can you check now?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS can you check now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61932561/4385913

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted ?

Comment: @Wicaledon have you solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do to solve the problem is add this on my `manifest.xml`

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

But you may have to use other approaches you can take a look on [android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted).

Answer (score 2):

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Add This line in your manifest application
It will allow to connect with without SSL certified URL

Answer (score 1):

You have to use http**s** with that api. Change:

```
private String BASE_URL = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/";
```

to

```
private String BASE_URL = "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/";
```

If you want to have a cleartext communication with the api you have to follow the steps from the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)